# Cypher Returning duplicate data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am stumped, but am sure that I am missing something obvious. In short, I have no idea why my query is returning 2x the values that I would have expected.

The screenshot below shows the query, the results of the query below it, as well as some baseline data (the bottom result set) that is accurate.

[image]

For example, team `B` really has played in 4 games, and had 10 points, but the second query at the top is returning 2x.

To follow along, here is my toy database:

```
// add constraint
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Team) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE;

// load the teams
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwXJE2qWVsejWeJGOouYxblNTox_Z9Ly5TWggzQNQVY/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv" AS row
WITH row
MERGE (t:Team {id:row.id, name:row.name});

// load the games
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwXJE2qWVsejWeJGOouYxblNTox_Z9Ly5TWggzQNQVY/pub?gid=33501648&single=true&output=csv" AS row
WITH row
CREATE (g:Game)
MERGE (h:Team {id:row.hometeam})
MERGE (a:Team {id:row.awayteam})
MERGE (a)-[:AWAY_TEAM {score:row.awayscore}]->(g)
MERGE (h)-[:HOME_TEAM {score:row.homescore}]->(g);

// Games played 
MATCH (t:Team)-[r]->(x:Game)
RETURN t.name, count(x) as games, sum(r.score) as for
ORDER BY games DESC

// the query in question which 2x's the results
MATCH (t1:Team)-[r1]->(g1:Game)
MATCH (g1)<-[r2]-(t2:Team)
RETURN t1.name, count(r1) as games, sum(r1.score) as for, sum(r2.score) as against
ORDER BY games DESC
```

And below is a viz of the entire graph, where the number on the edge is the score that team had in a particular game

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the query is that you are matching on each Team twice for each game played. In these two `MATCH` statements:

```
MATCH (t1:Team)-[r1]->(g1:Game)
MATCH (g1)<-[r2]-(t2:Team)
```

each Team is bound to both t1 and t2.

To fix it just add a `WHERE NOT t1=t2`:

```
MATCH (t1:Team)-[r1]->(g1:Game)
MATCH (g1)<-[r2]-(t2:Team) WHERE NOT t1=t2
RETURN t1.name, count(r1) as games, sum(r1.score) as for, sum(r2.score) as against
ORDER BY games DESC
```

Also, in your LOAD CSV import statement you should use the `toInt` function to be sure to cast integers properly (such as score):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwXJE2qWVsejWeJGOouYxblNTox_Z9Ly5TWggzQNQVY/pub?gid=33501648&single=true&output=csv" AS row
WITH row
CREATE (g:Game)
MERGE (h:Team {id:row.hometeam})
MERGE (a:Team {id:row.awayteam})
MERGE (a)-[:AWAY_TEAM {score:toInt(row.awayscore)}]->(g)
MERGE (h)-[:HOME_TEAM {score:toInt(row.homescore)}]->(g);
```

Comment: A follow up.  For team A, how can I get their opponents total score for games that team A did not play in within the same query?  For example, I want to use `MATCH (t1:Team)-[r1]->(g1:Game)<-[r2]-(t2:Team)-[r3]->(g2:Game)<-[r4]-(t3:Team)` but even after a number of `WHERE NOT` clauses, I am running into the same issue.  Struggling to wrap my head around why I am double counting these paths.

Comment: @Btibert3 If I understand you correctly it would be something like this: `MATCH (a:Team {name: "A"})-[]->(g:Game)<-[]-(opponent:Team)
MATCH (opponent)-[r]->(g2:Game)<-[]-(t2) WHERE NOT a=t2
RETURN opponent, sum(r.score) AS total_score`. Find all of Team A's opponents, find games those opponents played where they were not playing Team A, then sum that team's score for those game(s).

Comment: Thx again  Basically in the end i am trying to get at a team's score differential in the games they play in, and the differential for their opponents for the other  games that they played in.  I will play around and open a new question if I can't get all of there but this is a huge help.